# All the common elements present in the List of Python

Tags: python, list, element

Hi I am new to programming and want to learn python. I am working on a code that should return items that are most redundant in a list. If there are more than 1 then it should return all.
Ex.

```
List = ['a','b','c','b','d','a'] #then it should return both a and b.
List = ['a','a','b','b','c','c','d'] #then it should return a b and c.
List = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','d','d','d'] #then it should return a b and d.
```

Note: We don't know what element is most common in the list so we have to find the most common element and if there are more than one it should return all. If the list has numbers or other strings as elements then also the code has to work

I have no idea how to proceed. I can use a little help.

Here is the whole program:

```
from collections import Counter

def redundant(List):
    c = Counter(List)
    maximum = c.most_common()[0][1]
    return [k for k, v in c.items()if v == maximum]

def find_kmers(DNA_STRING, k):
    length = len(DNA_STRING)
    a = 0
    List_1 = []
    string_1 = ""
    while a <= length - k:
        string_1 = DNA_STRING[a:a+k]
        List_1.append(string_1)
        a = a + 1
    redundant(List_1)
```

This program should take DNA string and length of kmer and find what are the kemers of that length that are present in that DNA string.

Sample Input:

```
ACGTTGCATGTCGCATGATGCATGAGAGCT
4
```

Sample Output:

```
CATG GCAT
```

Comment: You're not returning anything from `find_kmers` function, use: `return redundant(List_1)`

Comment: Just for information if I have to input very long string in DNA_string how can I do that? DNA strings are very large smallest would be about a million in characters.Do I use pipe or there are other ways of working with long character string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
def solve(lis):
    c = Counter(lis)
    mx = c.most_common()[0][1]
    #or mx = max(c.values())
    return [k for k, v in c.items() if v == mx]

print (solve(['a','b','c','b','d','a']))
print (solve(['a','a','b','b','c','c','d']))
print (solve(['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','d','d','d'] ))
```

**Output:**

```
['a', 'b']
['a', 'c', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'd']
```

---

A slightly different version of the above code using `itertools.takewhile`:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import takewhile
def solve(lis):
    c = Counter(lis)
    mx = max(c.values())
    return [k for k, v in takewhile(lambda x: x[1]==mx, c.most_common())]
```

Comment: @thefourtheye My bad, fixed it. :)

Comment: @thefourtheye Actually you were partially correct, I should've used `iteritems` in the LC.

Comment: This looks good. Sorry I had to -1 to get your attention. I am putting it back.

Comment: I am not in favour of -1, I actually use that to get the attention. I believe in second chances ;)

Comment: Yes, the -1 method works nice. But, at times some people get pissed off for the wrong reasons :( @hcwhsa Thanks for such a nice code, now I just have to take a glance at the `collections` library instead of finding a tutorial. :)

Comment: I am getting NameError: global name 'Counter' is not defined seems Counter is not working for me I am using python 3.2.2

Comment: @user2954438 You need to import it first: `from collections import Counter`

Comment: I did use from collections import Counter if U want I can write all the code in here

Comment: @user2954438 It is working fine for me, no issues with import. http://ideone.com/63P5IE

Comment: Yes it did work for me too but it is not returning any value. Actually I am using it in conjunction with another function. One Function generates the list and from that list I need to find most common element. Here is my whole program:

Comment: @user2954438 Don't post your code in comments, it's unreadable. Post it in the question body.

Answer (score 1):

```
inputData = [['a','b','c','b','d','a'], ['a','a','b','b','c','c','d'], ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','d','d','d'] ]
from collections import Counter
for myList in inputData:
    temp, result = -1, []
    for char, count in Counter(myList).most_common():
        if temp == -1: temp = count
        if temp == count: result.append(char)
        else: break
    print result
```

**Output**

```
['a', 'b']
['a', 'c', 'b']
['a', 'b', 'd']
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for the sake of giving a solution not using `collections` & using list comprehensions.

```
given_list = ['a','b','c','b','d','a']
redundant = [(each, given_list.count(each)) for each in set(given_list) if given_list.count(each) > 1]
count_max = max(redundant, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
final_list = [char for char, count in redundant if count == count_max]
```

PS - I myself haven't used `Counters` yet :( Time to learn!

Comment: This is also wrong. He does **NOT** want to count the number of elements which occur more than once. Please read the question again

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> def maxs(L):
...   counts = collections.Counter(L)
...   maxCount = max(counts.values())
...   return [k for k,v in counts.items() if v==maxCount]
... 
>>> maxs(L)
['a', 'b']
>>> L = ['a','a','b','b','c','c','d']
>>> maxs(L)
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> L = ['a','a','a','b','b','b','c','c','d','d','d']
>>> maxs(L)
['d', 'a', 'b']
```

Comment: This is also wrong. He does **NOT** want to count the number of elements which occur more than once. Please read the question again.

Comment: @thefourtheye: Thanks for the bug report. Updated